# How can we calculate running time of an algorithm using the asymptotic complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If we are given the complexity of a certain algorithm, what the procedure to calculate the running time for N^3.

Comment: If any of the answer is sufficient please accept it. Otherwise comment on it to clarify why is the answer insufficient for you

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with this issue:

1. **Incremental**

We need to recalculate from n=50 to n=300 which is 6 times larger n. Given the complexity θ(n³) 6 times larger will result in 216 (6³) times longer running time. This gives us t=2160s for n=300

2. **Absolute**

The running time is some unknown constant x multiplied by the complexity n³. to find out the x we solve this equation: `t=x*n³` or rather `10=x*125000` which will give us final result of `x=1/12500`
Now we need to find new time for new n `t=(1/12500)*300³` which simplifies to `t=60*12*3` which gives us the same result of **2160** seconds.

Comment: That's a better answer than mine so I am deleting mine. If I could, I would upote.

Comment: In these two equations: t=x*n³ or rather 10=x*125000,  why are you replacing "t" with "10"?

Comment: The OP originally asked with given example of N=50 and running time t=10 seconds. The question was then edited to remove those values out of it after i have answered this question. See the question history https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35325513/revisions